# Is it still 'Honeymoon' if a couple does not go immediately after wedding; what's the synonym of honeymoon?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

MM, OALD, Collins, WordWeb, Reference --none of them helped me.

What is the synonym of the word ***'Honeymoon'?***

Also, dictionaries say that it's [the vacation](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/honeymoon_1) taken by a couple just after they have got married. But what if for some reason, the couple could not go **just after they got married** but go after 10-15 days. Is it **still** Honeymoon? Remember, this is the first time they are going together after their wedding.

My personal take on the word is...

> Honeymoon is *the first time outing (or getaway!) with your spouse for leisure and spousal love*

Help me.

Comment: Not aware of any synonyms. It also refers to an early period of a romantic relationship before reality (family, kids, money problems, etc) change the relationship forever (One might say "The honeymoon is over."). Check on etymology online [honeymoon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=honeymoon) and also Wikipedia [honeymoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeymoon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the couple left were only a couple weeks after the wedding ceremony, yes. After all, they are still newlyweds. One might call it a *delayed honeymoon*, if they felt the need to emphasize that the trip wasn't taken immediately after the wedding.

If the trip wasn't taken for a couple of years or more, sometimes you might see the phrase "the honeymoon we never had." That phrase is often used when a couple was unable to travel after they were first married, or if they weren't able to travel to a location as exotic as they would have liked. Google shows hundreds of instances of that exact phrase, and it shows up in many books, too:

> My husband David and I have been married for 17 years now, and after my transplant we went to Hawaii for **the honeymoon we never had**.
>
> <sup>Source: *Taking Flight: Inspirational Stories of Lung Transplantation More Journeys*, p. 164.</sup>

Comment: +1 for that expression - honeymoon we never had. It's so interesting to learn this phrase that way. A big thanks ;)

Comment: @MaulikV you might also be interested in the concept of a [second honeymoon](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/second-honeymoon).

Answer (score 1):

A honeymoon is a trip that a newly-married couple go on to have romantic time together before they begin mundane, day-to-day married life.

If this trip is delayed by a few weeks or a few months, people still call it a honeymoon. But at some point the couple is no longer "newly-married". Exactly when that is is hard to say. You can't say that a couple are newlyweds at 6 months into the marriage but not at 6 months and 1 day, any more than you can give a precise definition to how long a car is "new" or a person is "young".

Couples who have been married for a long time and who go on a special romantic trip together are often described as having a "second honeymoon".

Answer (score 0):

I would jokingly call a honeymood delayed by a couple of weeks a **raincheck honeymoon**. See [rain check](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rain_check) at Wiktionary. (0:

P.S. Someone [stole a march on](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/steal-a-march-on-sb) me with that. I've just found one news article titled "[Royal newlyweds take rain check on honeymoon](http://www.expatica.com/nl/news/european_news/royal-newlyweds-take-rain-check-on-honeymoon_145873.html)" from 2011.